# Autodesk forge viewer zooming to bounding box

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a bounding box object as below:

```
bb = {
  "min": {
    "x": -6.637446403503418,
    "y": -19.579801559448242,
    "z": -0.22575747966766357
  },
  "max": {
    "x": 10.237555503845215,
    "y": 19.15947914123535,
    "z": 9.774243354797363
  }
}
```

I want to zoom to this bounding box and make camera as centre.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `viewer.navigation.fitBounds( immediate, bounds )` to do this.

- The first argument, `immediate`, means that camera position will
  animate to the new location if immediate is set as false.
- The second argument, `bounds`, stands for the bounding box to fit.

Remember to convert your bounding box to `THREE.Box3 object`.

You can refer here for the API document: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/navigation/